# When using Transition to make the soldier aiming the gun how to make that it will keep aiming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Animator I have a Aiming state with transition to the Movement state and from the Movement back to the Aiming. And an Aiming parameter type bool.

When I click the mouse right button it's aiming but then switches right away back to movement without aiming.

In the Transition from Movement to Aiming the Aiming set to false and from Aiming to Movement aiming is set to true.

[image: Aiming]

And the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Soldier : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var inputVelx = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var inputVely = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Rotate(0, inputVelx, 0);

        anim.SetFloat("VelX", inputVelx);
        anim.SetFloat("VelY", inputVely);

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Aiming", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Aiming", true);
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm currently using GetMouseButton and as long as I'm holding the right mouse button down it will keep aiming.

But I want to use GetMouseButtonDown and to make it so that one click on the mouse right button will keep it aiming and clicking again will make the aiming false.

I tried to use GetMouseButtonDown but then it just aimed, then went back to false right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code inside your update function:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    anim.SetBool("Aiming", !anim.GetBool("Aiming"));
}
```